# Loop through dates modifying column value based on month

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes - time series and monthly averages as shown below

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1/10/2000', '3/11/2001', '6/12/2001', '4/03/2000', '23/07/2001', '15/07/2000', '05/05/2001', '17/12/2000', '9/9/2001', '2/24/2001'],
                   'value': [2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 7, 9, 4, 5, 6]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df

monthly = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                   'value_m': [0.49, 0.73, 0.88, 0.41, 0.77, 0.24, 0.40, 0.23, 0.51, 0.68, 0.17, 0.43]})
monthly
```

The goal is to loop through the dates and identify the month, then modify the value column in df dataframe by adding the corresponding monthly value from the monthly data frame. For example,  the first value of date is '1/10/2000' hence the month will be Jan (1) and the new value will be 2 + 0.49 = 2.49.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) with convert `monthly` `DataFrame` to `Series` with index by `month` and add to `value`:

```
df['value'] += df['date'].dt.month.map(monthly.set_index('month')['value_m'])
#working like
#df['value'] = df['value'] + df['date'].dt.month.map(monthly.set_index('month')['value_m'])
print (df)
        date  value
0 2000-01-10   2.49
1 2001-03-11   3.88
2 2001-06-12   4.24
3 2000-04-03   1.41
4 2001-07-23   4.40
5 2000-07-15   7.40
6 2001-05-05   9.77
7 2000-12-17   4.43
8 2001-09-09   5.51
9 2001-02-24   6.73
```

Performance for 10k rows:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
In [120]: %timeit df['value'] += df['date'].dt.month.map(monthly.set_index('month')['value_m'])
2.73 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [121]: %timeit df.value = df.apply(lambda x: get_new_value(x), axis=1)
299 ms ± 5.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
monthly_value = monthly.set_index('month')['value_m']

def get_new_value(data):
    try:
        value_m = monthly_value[data.date.month]
        return data.value + value_m
    except:
        return data.value


df.value = df.apply(lambda x: get_new_value(x), axis=1)
print (df)
```

Output:

```
       date    value
0   2000-01-10  2.49
1   2001-03-11  3.88
2   2001-06-12  4.24
3   2000-04-03  1.41
4   2001-07-23  4.40
5   2000-07-15  7.40
6   2001-05-05  9.77
7   2000-12-17  4.43
8   2001-09-09  5.51
9   2001-02-24  6.73
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time and answering my question. I sincerely appreciate